# TFrecord - How to print features correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, tfrecord

I made a tfrecords file that contains images and segmentation-images. I tried printing one record, but the image and segmentation-image do not match.

my code:

```py
def extract_features(data_record):
    features = {'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)}

    sample = tf.parse_single_example(data_record, features)

    image = tf.image.decode_image(sample['image'], dtype = tf.float32)        
    image = tf.reshape(image, [height, width, 3])

    label = tf.image.decode_image(sample['label'], dtype = tf.float32)        
    label = tf.reshape(label, [height, width, 3])

    return image, label

def create_dataset(ds_path):

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(ds_path)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(69863)
    dataset = dataset.map(extract_features, num_parallel_calls=8)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(1)

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    return iterator

iterator = create_dataset('train.tfrecords')
images, labels = iterator.get_next()

print(images.shape)
plt.imshow(tf.keras.backend.eval(images[0]))
plt.show()
plt.imshow(tf.keras.backend.eval(labels[0]))
plt.show()
```

When I try to show the data like this, the label and image are not matching. I think my mistake lies in my usage of tf.keras.backend.eval(), so I tried to use it only once like this:

```py
batch = iterator.get_next()
batch = tf.keras.backend.eval(batch)
images, labels = batch

print(images)

plt.imshow(images[0])
plt.show()
```

output:

```py
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_6:0", shape=(?, 540, 676, 3), dtype=float32)

TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

But then the images and labels are still tensors and I can't print them. Does anyone have an idea, how I could get this code to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the Tensor to np array first before showing.

```
images, labels = iterator.get_next()  # Get next Batch
img = np.asarray(images[0])  # First image of the batch
print(img)  # print images value
cv2.imshow("Image",img)  # Display image using cv2; not tested with pyplot.imshow(img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Works perfectly without any issue with tensorflow_gpu 1.14.0 in eager mode]

Comment: I tried to use this method but got a new error-message: **TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s**. So I tried to print the image information with print(img), after I used np.asarray() and got: **Tensor("strided_slice_7:0", shape=(540, 676, 3), dtype=float32)**

Comment: I still get the same error message and images[0] is still zero for me, but I found another solution: **images, labels = tf.keras.backend.eval([image_batch, label_batch)** did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

If the whole batch is converted with tf.keras.backend.eval([batch]), both the image and the label are from the same batch.

```py
images, labels = iterator.get_next()
images, labels = tf.keras.backend.eval([image_batch, label_batch])

print(images.shape)
plt.imshow(images[0])
plt.show()

print(labels.shape)
plt.imshow(labels[0])
plt.show()
```